# how to create an Appcelerator IOS module using multiple XIBs

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to create an Appcelerator IOS module, basically its a conversion of an App in Native to Appc module.

The Native Project has been created using XIBs.

So far i created a Proxy and used that view proxy to fetch the XIB using 
`[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle: bundle];`

I have converted the xibs to Nibs and have put them in the Asset folder of the Project invoking the module.

By doing all this i have been able to render the **ViewController** screen.But no events are working on this screen.

Here is the code rendering the second xib :

```
- (IBAction)handleStinkyClick:(id)sender {
     firstScreen *fs=[[firstScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"firstScreen" bundle:nil];
     fs.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
     URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory  inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
     [self presentViewController:fs animated:YES completion:nil];
  }
```

Is there anything i am missing?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I will ask an iOS engineer of use to have a look, but you might be interested in trying out Hyperloop for iOS, which lets you require XIBs and mix and match `Ti.UI.View` and *native* code.

http://labs.appcelerator.com/project/55f74a9f421c44837717716b/Hyperloop-Module

Comment: Thanks Fokke, i will check hyperloop but as its in beta right now, any idea by when it will be available in GA?

Comment: That will probably 6.0 in Q1.